# R Regex match the last occurance

Tags: r, regex

I've tried many things, but I'm still looking for a solution...

I have some text:

> blah blah blah...\nSlide rule exam does not provoke
>   symptoms.\nImPACT Test Date: ... (baseline done at school)\nVerbal
>   Memory Composite\n98\n98%\nVisual Memory Composite\n81\n69%\nVisual
>   Motor Speed Composite?38.83\n70%\nReaction Time\n0.59\n56%\nImpulse
>   Control\n9\nTotal Symptom Score\n3\nImPACT Test Date: ...
>   (post-injury done at school)\nVerbal Memory Composite\n54\n<1%\nVisual
>   Memory Composite\n35\n<1%\nVisual Motor ... blah blah blah

I would like to capture the last test score (in terms of sequence in the text) for the person. Right now I'm capturing the first (in terms of sequence in the text) test score.

This code captures the first Verbal Memory Composite score, in this case 98 and 98 (percent). I would like to capture the last one, in this case 54 and 1 (percent).

My current code:

```
re = ".*Verbal Memory Composite\n(\\S+?)\n(\\S+?)\n.*"
concussion.notes$IMPACT_VERBAL_MEM_NEW = as.numeric.score(with(concussion.notes, ifelse(grepl(re,NOTE_TEXT),sub(re,'\\1',NOTE_TEXT),'')))
concussion.notes$IMPACT_VERBAL_MEM_PCT_NEW = as.numeric.score(with(concussion.notes, ifelse(grepl(re,NOTE_TEXT),sub(re,'\\2',NOTE_TEXT),'')))
```

I tried gsub rather than sub, among other things, but still got 98.

Comment: Try `[\s\S]*Verbal Memory Composite\n(\S+?)\n(\S+?)\n` escaping it properly.

Comment: You don't need the last `.*` and, if the quotes unescape all escapes you need to escape the `\\n` as well. If they don't and just limited characters, just make it `\S` and `\n` respectively. Also, I would use `\r?\n` instead.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using a mixture of lazy and greedy quantifiers in the TRE regex pattern. Henry Spencer wrote his library in such a way that all quantifiers in the same branch should have the same greediness. In Tcl implementation, it is the first quantifier that sets greediness, in TRE, it is not always so.

Thus, you may just replace `\S+?` with `\S+`, and it will work.

However, you will get `<1%` in Group 2 (`\\2`). I suggest you use

```
".*Verbal Memory Composite\n[^\n0-9]*(\\d+)\\S*\n[^\n0-9]*(\\d+)\\S*\n.*"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/SRnWJc):

```
NOTE_TEXT <- "blah blah blah...\nSlide rule exam does not provoke symptoms.\nImPACT Test Date: ... (baseline done at school)\nVerbal Memory Composite\n98\n98%\nVisual Memory Composite\n81\n69%\nVisual Motor Speed Composite?38.83\n70%\nReaction Time\n0.59\n56%\nImpulse Control\n9\nTotal Symptom Score\n3\nImPACT Test Date: ... (post-injury done at school)\nVerbal Memory Composite\n54\n<1%\nVisual Memory Composite\n35\n<1%\nVisual Motor ... blah blah blah"
re = ".*Verbal Memory Composite\n[^\n0-9]*(\\d+)\\S*\n[^\n0-9]*(\\d+)\\S*\n.*"
sub(re,'\\1',NOTE_TEXT)
## => [1] "54"
sub(re,'\\2',NOTE_TEXT)
## => [1] "1"
```

The `\S+?` is replaced with `[^\n0-9]*(\\d+)\\S*`:

- `[^\n0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than newline and digits
- `(\\d+)`  - Group 1/2: one or more digits
- `\\S*`  - 0+ non-whitespace chars